# Ubuntu 15.04 black screen problem

Tags: 15.04

I have a problem with my Ubuntu 15.04.
The issue is simple, from time to time (4-6 hours) the screen turns black while I am working. The monitor shows that no cable is connected.

I have an HDD and an SSD. 
The SSD is for Windows (no problems, all working fine),
The HDD (350GB of 1TB) is for Ubuntu.

When I was working with Android Studio the screen goes black. After reset I had an empty Java file, but I am sure that I saved it.

Maybe it is an HDD issue?

Answer (score 0):

What monitor do you have? May be it's monitor setting, that after 4 or 6 hours it turns black, because for example LG monitor (I don't remember which model) have an option, that is set by default to turn screen black after 4h - it's monitor power saving mode.

Comment: Hello, It is not a problem with monitor setting, I am sure. I checked it. In my opinion meybe it is a problem with GPU and Ubuntu. When I installed drivers for my radeon R9 390, after reboot I have a black screen and monitor does not have a signal from GPU(orange LED, normally is Green). I had to remove this drivers to resolve this issue. 

ALso Orange LED is on monitor button when my problem occurs.(Tittle problem).